# Crystal Report exclude only numeric values

Tags: crystal-reports

On crystal reports i want to add a filter in formula editor to exclude any value that has only numbers.
I have a column which is car registratios and i dont want to load any data from where this carReg has a value with only numeric.

> Ex.  123456, KKT 689, KRT 254, 521684 I want to show only the KKT 689 and
>   KRT 254.

I have this already done in my database in an sql statement. But ill move the filter into the crystal report and i dont know the syntax for doing this in crystal.

Any ideas people?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new formula, and write in it the following:

```
if IsNumeric({carReg}) then 
  ""
ELSE 
  {carReg}
```

This formula suppresses the Numeric Car Registration numbers.

Comment: If i add this in Record Formula it says 'A boolean is required here'. And if i add it in Section Expert inside the suppress button it says 'The formula result must be a boolean'

Comment: did u fix the field names?

Comment: Yea i changed the field name.
if IsNumeric({CUSTOMERSTATEMENT2.CARNO}) then 
  ""
ELSE 
  {CUSTOMERSTATEMENT2.CARNO}

Comment: you need to add this in formula field and drag to report, you shouldn't add this in `Record Formula` or `Select Expert`

Comment: Yes this worked m8. 
The field now is empty when it needs to be, and i added this formula field in group expert to bring the right grid values. Cheers